# Как проверить существования ключа в объекте js?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {key: value}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Также можно использовать оператор опциональной последовательности (optional chaining), доступный начиная с ECMAScript 2020:

```
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    }
  }
};
```

Проверяем наличие ключа "c" в объекте "b", который является свойством объекта "a"

```
if (obj?.a?.b?.c) {
  console.log('Ключ "c" существует');
} else {
  console.log('Ключ "c" не существует');
}
```

В этом случае оператор "?" проверяет наличие свойств "a", "b" и "c" в объекте, и если хотя бы один из них отсутствует, то результатом выражения будет undefined. Если все свойства существуют, то выражение вернет значение ключа "c".

Comment: Способ рабочий, но только для какого-то конкретного кейса. Напиши
c: '' или c: 0 или c: null - и получишь не верный результат console.log('Ключ "c" не существует');
Исправить это можно применив метод поиска собственных свойств объекта hasOwnProperty:
if (!!obj?.a?.b && obj?.a?.b.hasOwnProperty('c')) {
  console.log('Ключ "c" существует');
} else {
  console.log('Ключ "c" не существует');
}

Answer (score 21):

свойство [in](http://javascript.ru/in) объект

```
key in obj
"foo" in ob
```

Comment: если конкретно этого объекта, то `hasOwnProperty('foo')` или `!!(Object.keys(a).indexOf('foo')+1)`

Answer (score 11):

```
if (typeof obj['key'] !== "undefined") {
//ключ есть
}else{
//ключа нет
}

if (typeof obj['key'] === "undefined") {
//ключа нет
}else{
//ключ есть
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Метод [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
 array.hasOwnProperty("имя поля")
```

Answer (score 8):

Вот так

```
if (typeof obj['key'] !== "undefined") {

}
```

Comment: неправда

    var obj={test: undefined};
    console.log(typeof obj['test'],typeof obj['test2']);

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал так:

```js
let obj = {
'key' : 'val',
'key1' : 'val1'
};
     
if(Object.keys(obj).includes('key1')){
console.log('Yes')
} else {
console.log('No')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Бывает так, что нам нужно проверить есть есть ли значение во вложенном объекте и если есть получить его значение, иначе вернуть значение по умолчанию
например
obj={
a:{ b:'valueB'},
c:"valueC"
}
Нужно проверить есть ли obj.a.b  и если есть вернуть valueB

```
check(strPath, value = null) {
      let iSValue = value;
      try {
        iSValue = eval(strPath);
      } catch (e) {
        iSValue = value;
      }
      return iSValue;
       },

  console.log("check", this.check("obj.a.b", "defaultValue")); // вернет valueB
  console.log("check", this.check("obj.s.a.b", "defaultValue")); // вернет defaultValue
  console.log("check", this.check("obj.s.a.b")); // вернет null
```